# Can someone help me make my Parallax / Section Background image mobile responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've tried a number of different html/css combinations, but I just can't seem to get my homepage background image responsive on mobile. I'm getting a stretched image on mobile.

I've also tried media queries, but nothing seems to work when I publish my site.

I should note however that when using my mobile emulator app on my desktop, everything seems to look great -- or like I want it to perform on mobile.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
<section id="aboveTheLine" class="js-parallax promo-block" style="background-image: url(/images/homedesktop.jpg);">


    <div class="container u-content-space">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h1 class="ai mt-5" style="font-size: 7vh">
            arctic<span class="ai-span" style="font-size: 7vh">insights</span>
          </h1>
          <h3 class="mb-5" style="color: #03045e; font-weight: 300; font-size: 3vh">
            The data clarity company
          </h3>
          <div class="scroll-downs">
            <div class="mousey">
              <div class="scroller"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

```
#aboveTheLine {
  background: no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

/*------------
/*Mobile*/
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #aboveTheLine {
    background-image: url(/images/homemobile.jpg);
  }
}

/*Tablet*/
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #aboveTheLine {
    background-image: url(/images/hometablet.jpg);
  }
}

/*Desktop*/
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  #aboveTheLine {
    background-image: url(images/homedesktop.jpg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Question, are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing `fixed` from your `background: no-repeat center center fixed;` section.